# What journals should I submit my paper to?

Tags: publications

I have a bachelor degree, but am currently not enrolled in a university. I am finishing a paper that I would like to publish in a fitting journal. Of course the ideal outcome would be a highly respected journal, but it seems to me that the odds of getting published are higher in a less well known journal.

I am considering just submitting it to the most highly respected journal, then going down the list until its accepted. Is this the optimal strategy?

The downside might be that the odds of those highly respected journals accepting my paper are very slim, so that the process will take years.

thoughts on this?

(as a side question: I did the research mostly during my bachelor degree, but I wrote it down, and finished it up after finishing my degree. Would it be fraudulent to name my university as my affiliation?)

Comment: The problem is that writing a paper worth publishing is a lot of hard work that takes years to perfect. Chances are you cannot make it alone without an advisor. Also, there is the problem that while you wrote your paper multiple people have already published papers on your subject. Have you checked recent bibliography to see if your paper can compete with those new papers? Having knowledge of everything  that was written in your paper's subject is the first step for acceptance.

Comment: Is this paper about work you did at the university?

Comment: I don't think you should use your university as an affiliation unless you are currently a student, faculty member, etc. Is there anyone you worked with on the research you can still contact? They may be willing to at least suggest a venue for your paper.

Comment: "*Of course the ideal outcome would be a highly respected journal*" - ideal for who? For you or for the scientific community? Is it really the best fit for your paper? It is **extremely** unlikely that research done by someone with a bachelor degree on his own is of suitable quality for such a journal.

Answer (score 2):

Check this site on Elsevier to find relevant journals for your work,
[Elsevier Journal Finder](http://journalfinder.elsevier.com/).
Also, Springer publisher have this one,
[Springer Journal suggester](http://journalsuggester.springer.com/).